how can I convert the firestore type Promise<DocumentData[] | undefined> into an array
I currently have an async function getMeds() that gets a user's medication collection and returns it. I want to assign the result to a variable and then map over the results, so that I have a React component for each entry in the array. However, when I try assigning the results from getMeds onto a variable, the IDE says

Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<DocumentData[] | undefined>'

export const getMeds = async () => {
    try {
        const user = auth.currentUser;
        if (user) {
            const snapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Users", user.uid, "Medications"));
            return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        }
    } catch (err: any) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}

I tried assigning the results to a useState variable in an async function in the frontend into either the array or an empty array:
const fetchDocuments = async () => {
    try {
      const docs = await getMeds(); // Await your async function
      setMeds(docs ?? []); // Set the fetched documents in state
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching documents:", error);
    }
  };

but I cant even create a useState variable, because typescript does not understand the type DocumentData[]. And if I try to just make the useState into an array, it then says I cannot assign typeDocumentData[] to it

Since you're not returning anything explicitly outside that if (user) conditional, the async function will return undefined in those other situations. You probably want to explicitly return an empty array in the else situation.

Did you try Derek's recommendation? Does it work for you?

Yes! It helped by changing the return type (it got rid of null) but I still can’t map through the result since it is of type Promise<DocumentData[]> and I don’t exactly know how to typecast this into an array when React does not recognize the type Promise<DocumentData[]>
